# How to add text before values in xml?

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlstarlet

Here is my test.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<path>
  <dir name="directory">
    <file name="file1"/>
    <file name="file2"/>
  </dir>
</path>
```

Now I can add some text after my values:

```
xmlstarlet ed -s "//file[@name]/@name" -t text -n "@name" -v "_copy_" test.xml
```

Result:

```
…
<file name="file1_copy_"/>
<file name="file2_copy_"/>
…
```

How can I add a text *before* values?

```
…
<file name="_copy_file1"/>
<file name="_copy_file2"/>
…
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the command line help, with `xmlstarlet ed`, you can use the *update* `-u` option and include a replacement XPath *expression* `-x`:

> `xmlstarlet ed -u <xpath> -x <xpath>`

In the replacement expression you can use an XPath `concat()` function to generate the string which will replace the attribute. The expression `concat('_copy_',.)` will concatenate the string `'_copy_'` *before* the *current node*, which is the attribute you are selecting. Your expression should be:

```
 xmlstarlet ed -u "//file[@name]/@name" -x "concat('_copy_',.)" test.xml
```

Comment: That's interesting. I tried this after installing the tool but the `-x` option does not seem to work. I found one version of the manual in which it says it has not been implemented yet.

Comment: `-x` (or `--expr`) was implemented in 1.2.0

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use the `tr` command of `xmlstarlet` you can obtain the desired result with the following helper XSLT `convert.xslt`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="*|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="file/@name">
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('_copy_', .)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the call

```
xmlstarlet tr convert.xslt test.xml
```